# MySQL Union in View

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm having 2 large tables, product and product_variants.
Currently I'm using a MySQL view, cause I need this SQL Statement many times.
The database structure cannot be changed atm.

Product:
ID | IsMaster | EAN | Name | Price ...

Product_Variants:
ID | PID (FK on Product.ID) | IsMaster | EAN | Name | Price ...

The view `my_view`contains a select like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM `product`) UNION (SELECT * FROM `product_variants`)
```

When I'm now doing a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_view WHERE EAN = '11110'
```

It takes about 0,5 up to 1 second.
If I would use the content of the view directly by adding `where` to each subquery, it is super fast (~0,004 sec):

```
(SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE EAN = '11110') UNION (SELECT * FROM `product_variants` WHERE EAN = '11110')
```

How can I use the faster method in the view? Am I needed to change to a MySQL function?

TIA
Matt

Comment: Can you get the data back as more columns (a join) rather than more rows (a union)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some mysql command to analyse your query as use EXPLAIN with select statement 
and check table and index structure.

use command

**set profiling=1;**

then use your select query
the use command

**show profiles for query1;**

check the result which thing is talking how much time.

and some other imp query are

*** SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl\G -- engine, indexes

- SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tbl'\G -- sizes
- EXPLAIN SELECT ...\G -- clues of inefficiencies
- SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%'; -- ca**

Comment: Using profiling returns that 0,3 seconds are used for `Sending data`. What does this mean herefor?

Comment: As per to my knowledge sending data term in mysql is used while scanning table for fetching result. so as you can see while you do first union and then use where close to fetch result,, then mysql scan your view fully and then fetch result according to your query
and in second case when you use "where" before "union" then mysql will scan less no of result 
because of pre-filtering where clause. For more information you can check select statement flow

Comment: No Actually, But i am trying to say that fetch only required  data using filter and subquery..
Views are great but only effective when used with profiled query.otherwise it will result a slow response. Subquery are effective to get response faster.Things that are making more rows will slow down you response. so analyse you query.

Comment: Thank your for explanation. I should check the query and optimize it? But How to use the information like EXPLAIN and the PROFILING shows me?

Comment: Check This Link:-http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/percona-live/dc-2012/PLDC2012-mysql-query-optimization.pdf            is my answer helpful enough?

Answer (score 2):

You might find this article helpful - http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/

The basic premise being that MySQL views are to help with writing uncomplicated SQL **not** with optimising code.

> [The] VIEW is simply expanded as a macro or Temporary Table in which case VIEW is materialized to temporary tables (without indexes !)

No index = slow select queries.

Comment: Your result is to delete the view? Index has been set already.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that the union inside the view is executed (without the benefit of a where clause) *before* the where clause is applied to filter those rows.

The effect is the select every row from both tables into a giant temporary table, then apply a where clause on that temporary table, without of course the benefit of an index (even if one existed on the base tables).

You could try using `UNION ALL` (rather than just `UNION`), because `UNION ALL` keeps all rows, whereas `UNION` discards duplicates, which masks the underlying table from the result due to the de-duping process.

---

The *real* problem is the database *design* - the two tables are so similar it's pretty obvious that there should be only *one* table with an `isVariant` column to distinguish the row type. If you can't change the tables, you could create a new table:

```
NewProduct
ID | PID (fk to self for variants, null otherwise) | IsMaster | IsVariant | EAN | Name | Price ..
```

And put indexes on whatever columns you're searching on (EAN in this case).

You could populate it once easily. To keep it in synch with the old tables, you could either truncate and re-run the population script manually whenever product info changes, or use triggers on the old tables to keep it in synch automatically. It depends what the details of your site are.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. This helps me and pushs the query down from 1 second to 0,7 seconds.
You mean I should try to build the query with joins instead of union?

Comment: Can your application handle getting the data side by side as a join?

Comment: Do you mean I should try using joins and not the union? What do you mean with side by side?

Answer (score 0):

Indexing the EAN Column in both the tables and try.

also try this

```
explain (SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE EAN = '11110') UNION (SELECT * FROM `product_variants` WHERE EAN = '11110')
```

Comment: The problem is that the query u wrote is ready in about 0,0002 seconds. But using the view with a where condition tooks up to 1 second.

Comment: don't put the where condition while creating view. View is just like temp table. it can be contain all the data related to your Select query. So you can use the where condition while getting the data from view. try this out.